# Why are my hibernate queries happening later than desired when I use JPA persist?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have a series of JPA persists and setter calls (updates) that are supposed to happen before the next lines of code get executed, but the logger is showing that the hibernate queries resulting from the persists are happening later than the next lines of code.

### The code

```
myDAO.persist(object1);               //insert 1
myOtherDAO.persist(object2);          //insert 2
object3.setProperty("value");         //update 1

System.out.println ("*****Message 1"); 
doWork();
System.out.println("*****Message 2");
```

### What the logger shows

```
Hibernate: insert into tableName1...  //insert 1
Hibernate: insert into tableName2...  //insert 2
*****Message 1
ERROR BECAUSE UPDATE DIDNT HAPPEN
*****Message 2
Hibernate: update table3 ...          //update 1 (too late)
```

So, instead of insert 1, insert 2, and update 1 all happening before the next lines of code, it seems that update 1 is actually happening too late.  Can someone tell my why this is happening to me and what I did to deserve it?

### EDIT

I should mention that this is in an integration test method, and doWork() is actually a mock request being sent to a servlet. The servlet is where the problem is occurring as it does not find the expected state in the database.  Is the servlet outside the transaction and effectively "going around the back" of hibernate? Should I flush before sending the request to the servlet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's normal and expected behavior. If Hibernate did an update query each time a persistent property is modified, the performance would be disastrous. The state of all the modified entities is persisted in database at flush time. The flush happens

- at commit time
- when you call `session.flush()` or `entityManager.flush()` explicitely
- when you execute a query (HQL or Criteria) that queries one of the tables of the modified entities

You should thus not have any error, except if you do a query "behind the back" of Hibernate, using JDBC or some native query. If so, flush explicitely before executng this query.

Comment: Even JPQL queries can go 'round the cache.

Comment: @jbnizet thanks for the reply, please see my update and provide any further feedback.

Comment: Then you have an even bigger comprehension problem. Transactions run in isolation from each other. That's one of the core principles of transactions (the I in ACID). So, by default (isolation mode set to read_committed), the servlet transaction won't see the changes done inside the test transaction, since it's not committed yet. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, it is a big comprehension problem as I am new to ORMs, integration testing, and JEE.  That's some good insight, though, and I learned a great deal from those links your provided.  When calling a servlet from a test transaction, is it customary to flush/commit the transaction before sending the mock request?

Comment: You have to commit it, else the servlet won't see anything. Flushing is not sufficient. Flushing just writes to the database the changes that are in the Hibernate cache, but doesn't commit.

Answer (score 1):

When working with ORMs, you need to keep your transaction in mind.  The ORM works within the bounds of a transaction, and will generally persist changes to the DB when 1) the tx completes, 2) it hits some kind of internal marker, or 3) when it is specifically instructed to flush to the DB, as JB Nizet noted.

If your code is depending on a specific DB state for a given object, e.g., another part of your code is going back to the DB to get data, and that part of the code depends on that object being in a certain state, you might need to go back to your code and rethink how it is written.  The calls might need to be in different transactions, or the objects in your ORM layer might have relationships that have not been set up in your entities (like a `OneToMany`).

In general, though, you really shouldn't need to do manual `flushes`; ORMs are generally very competent at keeping dependencies in mind when flushing to the DB.  In fact, in my own experience I've found that with the proper entity setup, I've only coded manual `flushes` when doing batch coding, as per the Hibernate manual.

Comment: thanks for the reply, please see my update and provide any further feedback.

Comment: Yes, based on your comment you appear to not be working in the same transaction, so the ORM is finishing when its tx boundary is reached,  but since your mock code is happening outside of the ORM's tx, the order is not happening as you expect.  Reconsider your testing code so that it all happens in the same tx, and all should be fine.